# Access log - помогите расшифровать пожалуйста. Не Get, a Head запросы

Tags: .htaccess, логирование

Помогите разобраться с логами. Сорян, но поиск дал, только общие ответы. Пишут что Head - может быть ддос атакой. ну это не для моего сайта точно.

1. Это означает что с этих доменов был переход на wcbiathlon, и потом пошел 301-й редирект? И если 301-й редиректит на мой же сайт (допустим на https) то почему в логах этого нет. Например 200-ответа с этих же ip.

```
wcbiathlon.ru 185.203.240.129 - - [08/Aug/2020:14:43:26 +0300] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 301 - "https://psyinspire.com" "Mozilla/7.0 (compatible; MSIE6.00; Windows 2004)"
wcbiathlon.ru 185.209.20.147 - - [08/Aug/2020:14:43:26 +0300] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 301 - "https://metrixdesign.ru" "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; MSIE7.00; Windows 2006)"
wcbiathlon.ru 85.209.89.224 - - [08/Aug/2020:14:45:15 +0300] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 301 - "https://pravda-o-coronaviruse.ru" "Mozilla/6.0 (compatible; MSIE3.00; Windows 2006)"
wcbiathlon.ru 212.86.109.31 - - [08/Aug/2020:14:45:16 +0300] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 301 - "https://potolkii.ru" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE3.00; Windows 2007)"
wcbiathlon.ru 85.209.89.205 - - [08/Aug/2020:14:45:44 +0300] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 301 - "https://1agm.ru" "Mozilla/7.0 (compatible; MSIE7.00; Windows 2007)"
```

2. А это уже Get запросы. И я не понимаю их смысл. Это переход с сайтов сауны на wcbiathlon? А потом 301-й редирект уводит их непонятно куда.

```
wcbiathlon.ru 37.229.196.63 - - [10/Aug/2020:03:34:39 +0300] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.0" 301 235 "https://sauni-moskva.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows XP)"
wcbiathlon.ru 37.229.196.63 - - [10/Aug/2020:03:34:40 +0300] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.0" 301 235 "https://sauni-moskva.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows XP)"
wcbiathlon.ru 37.229.196.63 - - [10/Aug/2020:03:34:40 +0300] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.0" 301 235 "https://sauni-moskva.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows XP)"
wcbiathlon.ru 37.229.196.63 - - [08/Aug/2020:09:09:42 +0300] "GET /season/ HTTP/1.0" 301 237 "https://sauna-v-ufe.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows XP)"
wcbiathlon.ru 37.229.196.63 - - [11/Aug/2020:11:15:09 +0300] "GET /season/ HTTP/1.0" 301 237 "https://sauni-lipetsk.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows XP)"
```

3. Не получается заблокировать бот MOZ-a.
   То есть все боты поблокированы.
   Этот отображается в логах так:

   ```
   compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com
   ```

Я пишу

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} dotbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DotBot/1.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DotBot [OR]
```

А он не блокируется